# "submit" text is showing up in image input type

Tags: html, image, button, input

I'm trying to create an image input that will change image from gatherHerb.jpg (default) to gatherHerb2.jpg when mousedown. The code actually works fine to do the intended but now a default sarif "Submit" is showing up over the image.

I've also tried setting value="" with no avail. Any help?

CSS first then HTML. Formatting is clearly an issue for me even on stack :(

```
#herbButton {
   border-radius: 5px;
   width: 100px;
   height:30px;
   background-image: url(buttons/gatherHerb.jpg)} 


<input type="image" id="herbButton" onClick="herbClick();"
    onMouseDown="document.getElementById('herbButton').style.backgroundImage='url(buttons/gatherHerb2.jpg)'"<br>
    onMouseUp="document.getElementById('herbButton').style.backgroundImage='url(buttons/gatherHerb.jpg)'"<br>
/>
```

Comment: Since it's a submit button, if you don't supply a value it will automatically hold the text 'Submit'. So naturally, you try to set the value to an empty string - problem is, this is also interpreted as having no value. What to do? Easy, just set the value to be a single space. I.e `value = ' '`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will help you out,

```
<input value=" " type="image" id="herbButton" onClick="herbClick();" onMouseDown="document.getElementById('herbButton').style.backgroundImage='url(buttons/gatherHerb2.jpg)'" onMouseUp="document.getElementById('herbButton').style.backgroundImage='url(buttons/gatherHerb.jpg)'" />
```

**See the update:** You should have a space in between `value=" "`,

So use `value=" "` instead of `value=""`

Answer (score 2):

don't use image as background of image your input type

use **src** attribute of input type image in your code like this

```
#herbButton {
   border-radius: 5px;
   width: 100px;
   height:30px;} 


<input type="image" src="buttons/gatherHerb.jpg" id="herbButton" onClick="herbClick();" onMouseDown="document.getElementById('herbButton').style.backgroundImage='url(buttons/gatherHerb2.jpg)'" onMouseUp="document.getElementById('herbButton').style.backgroundImage='url(buttons/gatherHerb.jpg)'" />
```

change src url to your complete url.

your will find more [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp)

Comment: Tried that too. When I use src in <input> it seems to trump the mouseEvents. Basically, image 1 always shows up. A fellow user suggested using value=" " with the space and that seems to have worked. Thanks still!